# Generate wrong answers from a list of correct answers

Tags: sql, sqlite

I want to write a query from a table that contains a question with a correct answer. And i want 3 more columns that are wrong answers that are generated from the correct answer column i did write a query but i think its not working perfectly.

```
 SELECT q1.Question, q1.Correct , q2.Correct Wrong1, q3.Correct Wrong2, q4.Correct Wrong3
From Questions q1 
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT correct FROM Questions ORDER by RANDOM() LIMIT 1) q2
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT correct FROM Questions ORDER by RANDOM() LIMIT 1) q3
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT correct FROM Questions ORDER by RANDOM() LIMIT 1) q4
ON q1.correct != q2.correct AND
q1.correct != q3.correct AND 
q2.correct != q3.correct AND 
q1.correct != q4.correct AND 
q2.correct != q4.correct AND 
q3.correct != q4.correct
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: What makes you think that your query does not work perfectly? It looks weird and I cannot see how `join` without `on` or `using` can make sense (compare https://www.sqlite.org/syntax/join-clause.html). But what would be really helpful would be a description of the result with an explanation why it is not good. Also, please provide some db definition and content for us to play with. SQLite commandline tool provides `.dump`, which is ideal for making a tailored toy database available as an [mcve].

Comment: Is it OK to have the correct answer always in the column which directly follows the question?

Comment: Your where clause allows q1.correct == q3.correct and q2.correct == q4.correct. You need more conditions, six in total.

Comment: Hi i did this: SELECT q1.Question, q1.Correct , q2.Correct Wrong1, q3.Correct Wrong2, q4.Correct Wrong3
From Questions q1 
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT correct FROM Questions ORDER by RANDOM() LIMIT 1) q2
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT correct FROM Questions ORDER by RANDOM() LIMIT 1) q3
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT correct FROM Questions ORDER by RANDOM() LIMIT 1) q4
ON q1.correct != q2.correct AND
   q1.correct != q3.correct AND 
   q2.correct != q3.correct AND 
   q1.correct != q4.correct AND 
   q2.correct != q4.correct AND 
   q3.correct != q4.correct

Comment: [Edit] your question to add more info, please. Do not forget to provide database structure and content, too. Make a tailored toy database as [mcve]. And show your output in contrast to desired output.

Answer (score 0):

I spent some time to create a perfectly elegant solution that used `CROSS APPLY` and `PIVOT` and then saw that the dbms was SQLite, and not SQL Server. Maybe someone else can take this and convert it to SQLite:

```
SELECT Question
    , Correct
    , Wrong1 = piv.[3]
    , Wrong2 = piv.[2]
    , Wrong3 = piv.[1]  
FROM 
(
    SELECT Question = q1.Question
        ,Correct = q1.Correct 
        ,ca1.Wrong 
        ,RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY q1.Question ORDER BY q1.Question)
    FROM Questions q1
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 3 Wrong = q2.Correct FROM Questions q2 WHERE q2.Correct <> q1.Correct ORDER BY NEWID()) ca1
) src
PIVOT
(
  MIN(Wrong)
  FOR RowNum IN ([1], [2], [3])
) piv;
```